# Creation of parallel threads for bulk request handling?

Tags: spring, multithreading, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have rest service and want to handle almost 100 requests in parallel for this service. I have mentioned number of threads and number of connections to create as 100 in my application.yml even i did not see 100 connections created to handle requests

Here is what i did in my application.yml

```
server.tomcat.max-threads=100
server.tomcat.max-connections=100
```

I am using yourkit to see the internals , but when i start its created only 10 connections to handle requests, when i sent multiple requests also the count of request handling threads not increased its remain as 10. see the attachment i took from yourkit.[image]

Comment: You're setting max threads. Not minimum threads. Tomcat in this case has decided the minimum should be 10.

Comment: Got it ,thanks AlexB. By using Jmeter i sent 70 requests then it created  70 threads to handle requests.

Comment: I have added my comment as an answer, if you want to accept it.

Answer (score 1):

You're setting max threads. Not minimum threads. Tomcat in this case has decided the minimum should be 10.